# chmod fails to alter permissions in Vagrant VM

Tags: cygwin, vagrant, snowplow

I am trying to set up a Vagrant environment to host Snowplow (https://github.com/snowplow). When I launch vagrant from a cygwin shell

> $vagrant up && vagrant ssh

I get into an Ubuntu guest image (12.04), and when I attempt to install java8 into this environment using ansible, I get this message:

> vagrant@precise64:~$ ansible-playbook
>   /vagrant/ansible-playbooks/java8-gradle.yml
>   --inventory-file=/vagrant/home/ansible/ansible_hosts --connection=local ERROR: The file /vagrant/home/ansible/ansible_hosts is marked as executable, but failed to execute correctly. If this is
>   not supposed to be an executable script, correct this with `chmod -x
>   /vagrant/home/ansible/ansible_hosts`.

The file is indeed 777:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 24 Mar  3 19:03 ansible_hosts*

but this same file is sync'd to the host (Windows) and cygwin shows the file as 644:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 rcoe Domain Users 24 Mar  3 14:03 ansible_hosts

Is there a known issue running in a headless (VirtualBox) Vagrant environment that doesn't allow permissions to be set on files that are sync'd to the host?

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried changing the permissions of the file in the guest and it failed to change them.  i.e., I tried chmod -x as the error message stipulated, as both the vagrant user and as root.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a known deficiency, but reportedly not a bug: [Changing shared folder permissions from within virtual machine](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/897)

There is a good [tutorial](http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/) on how to set up the synced folder in vagrant so that it would suit your needs - if you navigate to that link it will show the following snippet

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/sites/dev.query-auth", id: "vagrant-root",
   owner: "vagrant",
   group: "www-data",
   mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]
```

that shows how to adjust the permissions of the synced folder.

Alternatively you could also use a different method of syncing the folder, such as rsync (keeping in mind what the [trade-offs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html) are)

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/ryansechrest/Projects/Sites", "/var/www/domains", 
   type: "rsync"
```

More on that [here](http://ryansechrest.com/2014/04/unable-set-permissions-within-shared-folder-using-vagrant-virtualbox/)